# How can I revert the master branch to an old commit and cherry-pick a commit that was in mater?

Tags: git, cherry-pick

I have a change that I commited to my master branch. Other devs have also merged other feature branches into master after I made my commit. How would I revert master to a commit before mine and then merge only my change into master?

Right now I was planning to do these steps:

```
git checkout master
git reset --hard e3f1e37 
git push --force origin master
```

and then I would want to cherry-pick my change in. However, the branch that had my change has been deleted and only exists in the current master. Is there a way I can still cherry-pick this in?

Answer (score 1):

You can check `git reflog` for log of commits. By searching through the list of commits you should be able to pick those which you need and simply cherry-pick them.

For example your reflog will look like this

```
user$ git reflog
c9f9669 HEAD@{0}: commit: Fixed test cases to run on Unix
b3ca8a4 HEAD@{1}: pull: Fast-forward
54ba188 HEAD@{2}: pull origin master: Fast-forward
e659a21 HEAD@{3}: reset: moving to HEAD~1
12944d8 HEAD@{4}: reset: moving to HEAD~1
6f40152 HEAD@{5}: reset: moving to HEAD~1
3de61ba HEAD@{6}: pull: Fast-forward
e659a21 HEAD@{7}: reset: moving to HEAD^1
12944d8 HEAD@{8}: reset: moving to HEAD^1
6f40152 HEAD@{9}: reset: moving to HEAD^1
3de61ba HEAD@{10}: commit: Removed Query object
6f40152 HEAD@{11}: pull: Merge made by the 'recursive' strategy.
12944d8 HEAD@{12}: commit: API touchups
e659a21 HEAD@{13}: commit: Test enhancements
07419e1 HEAD@{14}: pull: Fast-forward
```

The commits that you're looking for are ones with hash `3de61ba` and `12944d8`

```
git cherry-pick 3de61ba
git cherry-pick 12944d8
```

It should be pretty simmilar to what you need.

More info on how the `reflog` works and how to use it you can find in the [official Git documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog)